# dict() in for loop - different behavior

Tags: python, json, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to update values for a `dict()` key dynamically with a for loop.

```
def update_dict():
    f = []
    for i, j in enumerate(list_range):
        test_dict.update({'a': i})
        j['c'] = test_dict
        print(j)
        f.append(j)
    print(f)

test_dict = dict({'a': 1})
list_range = [{'b': i} for i in range(0, 5)]
update_dict()
```

Even `print(j)` gives iterating value `(0,1,2,3,4)`, somehow the last dict is getting overwritten all over the list and giving wrong output `(4,4,4,4,4)`.

Expected Output,

```
[{'b': 0, 'c': {'a': 0}}, {'b': 1, 'c': {'a': 1}}, {'b': 2, 'c': {'a': 2}}, {'b': 3, 'c': {'a': 3}}, {'b': 4, 'c': {'a': 4}}]
```

Output obtained,

```
[{'b': 0, 'c': {'a': 4}}, {'b': 1, 'c': {'a': 4}}, {'b': 2, 'c': {'a': 4}}, {'b': 3, 'c': {'a': 4}}, {'b': 4, 'c': {'a': 4}}]
```

I need to understand how the dictionaries are getting overwritten and what could be the best solution to avoid this?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. : please avoid suggesting list or dict comprehension method as bare answer as i am aware of them and the only purpose of this question is to understand the wrong behavior of dict().

Comment: `test_dict` is the same for all dicts. Updating it at any time updates all the sub-dicts.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre While debugging i see different values are there in every iteration

Comment: of course, but all the previously stored values are changed

Comment: So the dict.update() updates all the values inside the list?

Comment: you're pointing `j['c']` to `test_dict`, which gets updated in each iteration, final `'c'` reflects the last value of `test_dict`. what's so confusing about it?

Comment: The confusion is how does last iterative value of 'c' is overwriting in all dict across the list?

Comment: `j['c']` doesn't create any new value, it's pointing to a single object, `test_dict`. add this to your script, `j['c'] = test_dict, id(test_dict)` and see how that's a single dict object outside of that function.

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks @cryptonome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of such behaviour is that all references in list points to the same dict. Line `j['c'] = test_dict` doesn't create copy of dictionary, but just make j['c'] refer to test_dict. To get expected result you need change this line to:
`j['c'] = test_dict.copy()`. It will make deep copy of test_dict and assign it to j['c'].

Answer (score 2):

You try to add values to same dictionary every time in the loop and as loop progresses, you keep replacing the values.

You need to define dictionary in every iteration to create *separate* references of the dictionary:

```
def update_dict():
    f = []
    for i, j in enumerate(list_range):
        test_dict = {'a': i}
        j['c'] = test_dict
        f.append(j)
    print(f)


list_range = [{'b': i} for i in range(0, 5)]
update_dict()

# [{'b': 0, 'c': {'a': 0}}, 
#  {'b': 1, 'c': {'a': 1}},
#  {'b': 2, 'c': {'a': 2}},
#  {'b': 3, 'c': {'a': 3}},
#  {'b': 4, 'c': {'a': 4}}]
```

Comment: you're right, my bad, see that your code could be simplified

Comment: Great! This works fine. But what if test_dict contains more keys like `test_dict = dict({'a': 1, 'b':'c'})` and i don't want 'b' to be changed?

Comment: So you can have `test_dict = {'a': i, 'b': 'c'}` inside the loop. Value of `b` will always be `c`.

Comment: What i have given in question is sample code only. In original my `test_dict` may contain several keys and i need to update any one key among them. I am afraid i can't use your suggestion in my use case.

Comment: @SmashGuy Yes, you could do this way. See my previous comment. There, only value of key `a`changes but other one remains the same.

Comment: @Austin, thanks for your efforts. dict.copy() seems more dynamic and I am going with it.

Comment: @SmashGuy, No worries. :)

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution could be to iterate through `list_range` and create `c` using the values from `b`

```
lista = [{'b': i } for i in range(0, 5)]
for i in lista:
    i['c'] = {'a': i['b']}
# [{'b': 0, 'c': {'a': 0}}, {'b': 1, 'c': {'a': 1}}, {'b': 2, 'c': {'a': 2}}, {'b': 3, 'c': {'a': 3}}, {'b': 4, 'c': {'a': 4}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def update_dict():
   f = []
   for i, j in enumerate(list_range):
        j['c'] = {'a': i}
        print(j)
        f.append(j)
   return f

list_range = [{'b': i} for i in range(0, 5)]
print(update_dict())

#output
{'b': 0, 'c': {'a': 0}}
{'b': 1, 'c': {'a': 1}}
{'b': 2, 'c': {'a': 2}}
{'b': 3, 'c': {'a': 3}}
{'b': 4, 'c': {'a': 4}}
```